# Text Change event of textbox automatically fires when postback accurs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox in webuser control. And i am accessing it in content page and add its text

change event handler as follow...

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Find = (TextBox)(Menu1.FindControl("txtTarget"));
  Find.TextChanged += new EventHandler(Find_TextChanged);
}
void Find_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Now i have a linkbutton in the same web user control. when i click this linkbutton the text change event of that text is automatically fires.

How i can stop this event to occur when click the link button?

Comment: TextChanged event will be fired when you change the value of Text property. If you are not interested to handle it then remove the event handler.

Comment: But i have need it in other cases. I have no need of this event when i am clicking the link button.

Comment: Button's click wont raise  TextChanged and call the handler except its value has been changed.

Comment: If you don't need it, remove the event handler. Otherwise, exclud the code inside de Page_PreInit method and the void Find_TextChanged method.

Comment: Textchange event fires before the button click event fires. So what i would have to do?

Comment: dev but i have need this event.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with event handler execution. (Read page life-cycle of asp.net msdn pages). Now, my question is what do you want to do?

Comment: Actually i have a ajax slider. when slider moves then the textbox value changes and its change event is fired where i have implementa logic . my slider is in a webuser control. now i have a link button in same user control. when i will click it the text change event is fired automatically.Now i want that text change event is fired only when slider is move not when button is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time the textbox posts back, it checks its value; if different than the previous server value, it fires the TextChanged event.  I don't believe there are any ways around that.  However, what I think you can do is put an if condition that if the link button was clicked, ignore the handle:

```
void Find_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //if link to ignore, exit
     if (Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET") == lnkLinkToIgnore.UniqueID)
       return;


 }
```

It may be ClientID, but I'm pretty sure it posts the UniqueID, and therefore, you can check that the link caused the postback not process TextChanged.